# How do I stop new text in a cell overlapping the old text in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

This is an issue which has only started with my new computer. Whenever I go into the top left box to edit a cell, any time I type in the middle of what's in that cell, it will delete the following letter, replacing it with what I just typed for no reason. I want to turn this off as it's quite annoying.

Example:

How I want it to work:

1. Cell says “Food” in it
2. I click in between the two “o”-s in the top left and type the letter “f”
3. Cell now says “Fofod”

How it currently works:

1. Cell says “Food” in it
2. I click in between the two “o”-s in the top left and type the letter “f”
3. The letter “f” overwrites the next letter along, removing the “o”
4. Cell now says “Fofd”

Answer (score 0):

This is something that is caused by your keyboard insertion mode, not by Google Sheets.

Press the <kbd>Insert</kbd> to change from overwrite mode to insert mode.

Reference

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key